# PyCharm: no Python terminal to type in

Tags: python, pycharm

I have installed PyCharm and Python and uninstalled them many times.

Whenever I make a new project, it just shows "go to file", "Search everywhere", etc. instead of an area where I can put code. How can I fix it?

[Picture of my PyCharm project error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvQmH.png)

Comment: This is not an error. You need to create a file first. Right click on the root directory, then *New* and *Python File*. Alternatively, use Ctrl + Alt + Insert.

Comment: When I click new it doesnt show python file

Comment: Use *File* then. Remember to put the extension at the end of your file name; for example: `foo.py`.

Comment: Thanks it worked but when i tried to run it it says run has nothing to show. Do you know how to fix it

Comment: Error running 'PLC_PUMP_GALLONS' Python script path must be set

Comment: Please provide enough details to replicate the problem, preferably in another question.